# Entity Framework Fluent API For Custom validations

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Is there any way we can create a method to use in Fluent API just like how we create a custom validation attribute by inheriting the ValidationAttribute class?

Comment: Fluent API of what? The most probable solution for what I _guess_ you are looking for would be an [extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods). But that's a guess. Can you elaborate a bit, maybe give an example of what you are trying to achieve (even if it is not working right now, just show what it shall "look like")?

Answer (score 1):

## Generally speaking for any Fluent API

You can make custom extensions to Fluent APIs by implementing [extension methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods).

Here is an example:

```
public static class DependencyInjectionExampleExtension
{
    /// <summary>From experience: good idea to document what this does</summary>
                                                  // vv this 'this' is important!!
    public static IServiceCollection AddMyServices( this IServiceCollection services )
    {
         services.AddSingelton<IMyService, MyService>(); // Just an example
         return services;
    }
}
```

Then you can use this like so:

```
// doing DI setup ...
services.AddAuthentication()
        .AddMyServices() // <-- there it is
        .AddSomeOtherStuff();
```

This example is around `IServiceCollection`, but you can extend other interfaces or types just as well.

---

## Heads up

If you are trying to do this for **Entity Framework (Core)**, this *may not always be possible*.

I mean: You totally *can* do something like for example a `WhereIf` that adds a where clause to an `IQueryable` if a condition is true. That is basically just adding syntactic sugar.

*But*: Whatever you do must still be translateable to SQL. So you *may* run into boundaries, here.